# how make bottomsheet in fragment not transparent

Tags: android, android-fragments, bottom-sheet

I want make bottomSheet in fragment (fragment of nawDrawer). I did it with google guidelines in pre L target API.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_help, container, false);
    View bottomSheet = v.findViewById(R.id.bottom_shit);
    mBottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet);
    final LinearLayout test = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.calls);
    test.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            mBottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
        }


    });
    mBottomSheetBehavior.setBottomSheetCallback(new BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onStateChanged(@NonNull View bottomSheet, int newState) {
            // React to state change
        }

        @Override
        public void onSlide(@NonNull View bottomSheet, float slideOffset) {
            // React to dragging events
        }
    });

    return v;
}
```

And in result I can see part of fragment layout when `bottomSheet` expanded.

Some smart guys told me to set background color in `bottomSheet` layout - no way. Layout became colorized, but I can see those fragment.

What I've done wrong?